# Pushing app to bluemix

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ibm-cloud

I am trying to push my angular express web app to bluemix, but I am getting this error

```
2016-04-05T20:12:50.96-0300 [App/0]      OUT > angular-expess-seed-
with-html@0.0.1 start /home/vcap/app
2016-04-05T20:12:50.96-0300 [App/0]      OUT > node app.js
2016-04-05T20:12:51.19-0300 [App/0]      OUT Express server listening      
 on port 3000 in production mode
2016-04-05T20:13:50.37-0300 [DEA/34]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed    
to start accepting connections
2016-04-05T20:13:50.39-0300 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with    
guid b3554c4b-11f5-433f-891e-1df16605df80 payload:  
{"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"b3554c4b-11f5-433f-891e-
1df16605df80", "version"=>"36d8b569-d38a-465d-8bc6-b14ffd13b413", 
"instance"=>"dbd3566e0ef348d9b9f483a32e8fed89", "index"=>0,  
"reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>-1, "exit_description"=>"failed to 
accept connections within health check timeout", 
"crash_timestamp"=>1459898030}
 2016-04-05T20:13:50.40-0300 [App/0]      ERR
 2016-04-05T20:14:16.36-0300 [DEA/24]     OUT Starting app instance      
  (index 0) with guid b3554c4b-11f5-433f-891e-1df16605df80
```

First it was complaining about the start script missing I've fixed that part but no such with this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see from the error below:

```
Express server listening      
 on port 3000 in production mode
```

that your Node.js application is trying to listen in port 3000. That works in local environment, but for Bluemix you have to get the port from the Cloud Foundry (CF) environment.

Here is a sample code to do that:

```
// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {

        // print a message when the server starts listening
  console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex da Silva